# Emiting event from component to parent module cousing exception

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Counter } from './counter'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <custom-counter [(counter)]="counterArray" (counterChange)="myValueChange($event);"></custom-counter>
<p><code>counterValue = {{counterValue}}</code></p>
<hr>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges{
    counterArray:Counter[]
    counterValue = 5;
    constructor(){
      this.counterArray=[{id:0,value:0},{id:1,value:1}]
    }
    myValueChange(event:Counter[]) {
       console.log(event);
    }
 }
```

my counter.ts

```
export class Counter {
  id: number;
  value: number;
}
```

and custom-counter  component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Counter } from './counter';
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-counter',
  template: `
  First counter
    <button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
    <span>{{this.counter[1].value}}</span>
    <button (click)="increment()">+</button>
  `
})
export class CustomCounterComponent {
  @Input() counter : Counter[];
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();
  decrement() {
    this.counter[1].value--;
        this.counterChange.emit({
      value: this.counter
    })
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter[1].value++;
        this.counterChange.emit({
      value: this.counter
    })
  }
}
```

My plan was that if user presses button on from the child component parent is informed about it and print something in console.
unfortunately when  user press button error below is thrown:

> "Error in ./CustomCounterComponent class CustomCounterComponent - inline template:3:10 caused by: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

I know that this exception is quite strait forward but I can not find why something is undefined while I pass everything.

If I comment out lines with `emit` no error occur but then I do not have any notifications for parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in in-proper calling the emit method.

Calling like this:

```
this.counterChange.emit({
  value: this.counter
})
```

was creating new object that was emited and that someway messed object binding. ( If anyone can explain this better then please do it).

after changing call to this:

```
this.counterChange.emit(this.counter)
```

when I emit strait the input object everything started to be working.

Comment: That is because your event expects an object of type Counter[]. Where as the value you have passed is an object it should be an array of type Counter. Can you confirm if I'm going in the right direction?

Comment: exception is saying about 'value' parameter and not about id. Also i tried with type set to `any` and  i received same exception

Comment: you passed an object and not an array

Comment: For those interested, I've created a simple example of how to pass data between parent and child components here: https://github.com/agenoria/simple_angular_input_output_example. It is loosely based on this question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your CustomCounterComponent class the template has an issue.

Try the following in your template:

```
template: `
 First counter
<button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
<span>{{counter[1]?.value}}</span>
<button (click)="increment()">+</button>
`
```

? is a safety operator that would not throw an exception when counter[1] is undefined

Also note this is not required with counter in the template

The following method expects an an Array whereas it receives an object.

```
 myValueChange(event:Counter[]) {
   console.log(event);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but are you sure about that? I thought that child module will be called after parent is constructed so that array should be already initialized.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The array is not empty but 'this' is not required in the template for interpolation. this.counter[1].value should be counter[1].value and also it is a good practice to use the safety operator to avoid undefined exceptions on arrays.

Comment: unfortunately not but thanks for trying to help. I will post my answer in couple of minutes